# How can I use the Social Tables API without authorizing every time

Tags: social-tables

I have a server-based application that needs to add guest lists, but, I don't see any method to do this without performing a /oauth/authorize every time, as the code expires almost immediately after granting access.

Comment: Hi David, can you write out the steps you are taking in the oauth flow? The token has a much longer expiration date than that.

Comment: I use it once, five minutes later it tells me it's expired.

Comment: I use it once, five minutes later it tells me it's expired.  I use the https://auth.socialtables.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXX0&redirect_uri=XXX.com/myurl&grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=code to get the code, then use this code to get the token (/oauth/token?code=CodeThatIGotBack), but, it returns expired a) I run it a few mins after the /authorize, or b) I use the same code again.  How am I supposed to use the API if I have to login every time using the browser to get a new code?  This is very frustrating.  The example you give is a WEB app, not a server side app.

Comment: So, I perform the /oauth/authorize, login to the website, get the code parameter passed back, pass that code to /oauth/token?code=<theCode>&client_id=<myClientId>&client_secret=<myClientSecret>&grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=token and it says "Code has expired".  Surely a better way...I've tried the refresh approach, using /oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&code=<theOriginalCode> but it also says expired (I believe).  HELP!

Comment: So, is the only support option to post to this site and wait for days on a response?

Comment: There is a phone number that I've called before, but didn't have much luck. I'd say that I've hard marginal luck with getting the needed help through Stack Overflow. That is bizarre that it's expiring so soon, mine seem to last about 2 weeks.